# C++ Array Search and Summary

Tags: c++, arrays, search, report, file-io

EDIT:

I have made the following changes to my code:

```
ifstream infile;

infile.open("sales.txt");

if ( !infile.is_open() ) cerr << "file didn't open" << endl;

if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Forget something?"
        << endl;
    return 1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < empl; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < dps;  j++)
        cin >> data[i][j];

items = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < empl; row++)
    items = items + data[row][item];

money = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < dps; row++)
    money = money + data[row][sale];
taxes = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < empl; row++)
        taxes = taxes + data[row][tax];



itemsOne = 0;
itemsTwo = 0;
itemsThree = 0;
itemsFour = 0;
itemsFive = 0;

for(row = 0; row < dps; row++)
{
    if(idOne == data[row][ID])
    {
        itemsOne += data[row][item];
    }
    if(idTwo == data[row][ID])
    {
        itemsTwo += data[row][item];
    }
    if(idThree == data[row][ID])
    {
        itemsThree += data[row][item];
    }
    if(idFour == data[row][ID])
    {
        itemsFour += data[row][item];
    }
    if(idFive == data[row][ID])
    {
        itemsFive += data[row][item];
    }
}



cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "Employee 100 sold : " << itemsOne << endl;
cout << "Employee 200 sold : " << itemsTwo << endl;
cout << "Employee 300 sold : " << itemsThree << endl;
cout << "Employee 400 sold : " << itemsFour << endl;
cout << "Employee 500 sold : " << itemsFive << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "Total items sold : " << items << endl;
cout << "Total revenue :" << revenue << endl;
cout << "Sales Tax: " << taxes << endl;
cout << "Gross Income: " << money << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "so long and thanks for all the fish" << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;   


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I have manually checked the logic with an array put in the old fashion way and am getting zero values for itemsFour, itemsFive, and bizarrely the sales data from the 500 sub-array is not going through.

So I have been working on a project and have hit a bit of a stumbling block. My goal is to take the following array from a the following text file:

```
ID  Items Sales Tax
100 23    1200   110
200 12    7500   120
100 10    1000   230
300 11    1100   110
500 47    5800   122
```

And find the items sold by each employee, the total items sold, the total sales, and the total tax.

Here is the code that outputs nothing but a series of zeros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


const int empl = 5;
const int dps = 4;
float data [empl][dps];
int row;
int col;
double itemsOne, itemsTwo, itemsThree, itemsFour, itemsFive, items, revenue, taxes, money;
int item = 1, sale = 2, tax = 3;
float idOne = 100, idTwo = 200, idThree = 300, idFour = 400, idFive = 500;


int main()
{
ifstream infile;

infile.open("sales.txt");

infile >> data[empl][dps];


items = 0;
    for (col = 0; col < dps; col++)
    items = items + data[item][col];

taxes = 0;
    for (col = 0; col < dps; col++)
        taxes = taxes + data[tax][col];

money = 0;
        for (col = 0; col < dps; col++)
        money = money + data[sale][col];

itemsFour = 0;
for(col = 0; col < dps; col++)
{
    if(idOne = data[0][col])
    {
        itemsOne += data[1][col];
    }

    if(idTwo = data[0][col])
    {
        itemsTwo += data[1][col];
    }

    if(idThree = data[0][col])
    {
        itemsThree += data[1][col];
    }


    if(idFour = data [0][col])
    {
        itemsFour = itemsFour + data[1][col];
    }

    if(idFive = data[0][col])
    {
        itemsFive += data[1][col];
    }
}


revenue = money + taxes;


cout << "***********************************" << endl;      //Step 5 outputs report to command line
cout << "Employee 100 sold : " << itemsOne << endl;
cout << "Employee 200 sold : " << itemsTwo << endl;
cout << "Employee 300 sold : " << itemsThree << endl;
cout << "Employee 400 sold : " << itemsFour << endl;
cout << "Employee 500 sold : " << itemsFive << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "Total items sold : " << items << endl;
cout << "Total revenue :" << revenue << endl;
cout << "Sales Tax: " << taxes << endl;
cout << "Gross Income: " << money << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "so long and thanks for all the fish" << endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;   


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but this is an out of bounds array access: `infile >> data[empl][dps];`

Comment: If you think `infile >> data[empl][dps];` populates your entire 2D array from your input file, you're mistaken.

Comment: Also, I don't see any initialization of `itemsOne`, `itemsTwo`, `itemsThree` and `itemsFive`

Comment: Ah yes, that was a silly mistake. Any advice on how best to initialize and put my array in bounds? Is it a problem with the column and row size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some for-loops to populate your `data` array.  Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < empl; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < dps; j++)
        cin >> data[i][j];
```

Note that if your data file has headers on it as your example does above, you'll need to read and discard those *before* this loop.  Something like `string temp; std::getline(cin, temp);` would do.

In the loops that compute `items`, `taxes` and `money`, you have row and column switched, I think.  If your first index is `empl`, which goes 0..4, then you ought to switch these like so:

```
items = 0;
for (row = 0; row < empl; row++)
    items = items + data[row][item];
```

I believe you need to make the same switch in the big loop that follows these as well.

And finally, in these statements, you need to use `==`, not `=` to compare values:

```
if(idOne == data[0][col])  // use == here, not =
{
    itemsOne += data[1][col];
}
```

I haven't vetted the logic of your code to great detail, but if you fix these items, you'll be in better shape and can get to the next steps.

Comment: Ok so I have changed the logic where you indicated and but I am still struggling with getting the text file data into my array. I am currently using this code:
     `int i = 0;

 int a, b, c, d;
 for(int i = 0; i < empl; i++)
  while(i < empl && infile >> a >> b >> c >> d)
  {
    data[i][dps] = a;
    data[i][dps] = b;
    data[i][dps] = c;
    data[i][dps] = d;
    ++i;
  }`
But I am still facing the problem with all zeros.

Comment: @user3093333 :  Please try using the loop I wrote at the top of my answer above.  The loop you wrote in that comment will not work.  For one, it's using `dps` as an array index, but it's not a valid array index.

Comment: So I have used the for loop above but it is still populating all zeros.

Comment: @user3093333:  Are you sure it's populating `data` with all zeros, or that the rest of your logic produces all zeros?  Can you single step in a debugger and view `data` in there?  Also, are you certain `infile.open("sales.txt");` succeeded?  You can check it with `if ( !infile.is_open() ) cerr << "file didn't open" << endl;`

Comment: So I made an edit to the original code and have explained the problems underneath the new code.

Comment: Your big for-loop at the end should have `i < empl`, not `i < dps`.  Likewise for the loop that calculates `money`.  Also, does your data file have a row of header information like the example in the text, or is it just numbers?  If it has a row of header information, you need a call to `getline()` to read and discard the header, as I described in my answer above.

Comment: Sorry about that, the row header was just for demonstrative purposes. But the empl vs dps problem was the answer the other issues. I really appreciate getting another set of eyes on this, I've been working 12 hour days for the past month and it makes it hard to spot the little things.

Comment: I'm at a loss now.  Have you single-stepped through the for-loops that read from `cin >> data[i][j]`?  After the loops is `cin.good()` true?

Comment: Done both, still zeros. I honestly think it is visual studio that is giving me the grief because I have gone through the (admittedly little) amount of debugging that I know.

Comment: You don't accidentally have a stray, empty `sales.txt` file laying around do you?

Comment: Ha! I did actually, weird that it could be something so simple. Again, I really appreciate all of your help. Thanks again for everything.